# Viewshed analysis of two buildings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I'm very new to ArcGIS having used Global Mapper in the past to do simple viewshed analyses of factory stacks at a given radius.

Now I need to produce a 2km radius ZTV of two buildings next to each other each of a given height.

I have the footprints in CAD saved out as DXF (though I realise this may be bad practice?!) and the DTM in place (UK Ordnance survey ASC tiles), but I cannot work out how to extrude those buildings in ArcGIS and perform a viewshed analysis on them?